# Angular PrimeNG || Unable to autofit column width for Table Horizontal and Vertical

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable, primeng-turbotable

I have created p-table with Horizontal &Vertical scrollable table using PrimeNG. 
It’s contains more rows & columns.

Here, I’m facing the challenges unable to adjust the column width automatically instead of hard-coding width.

```
<ng-template pTemplate="colgroup" let-columns>
  <colgroup>
    <col *ngFor="let col of columns" style="width: 200px">
  </colgroup>
</ng-template>
```

Below are the code.

```
<p-table [columns]="th" [value]="tbody" [rows]="100" [paginator]="true" 
[totalRecords]="resultCount" 
  [lazy]="true" (onLazyLoad)="pagination($event)"
[pageLinks]="3" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[100]" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="500px">
<ng-template pTemplate="colgroup" let-columns>
  <colgroup>
    <col *ngFor="let col of columns" style="width: 200px">
  </colgroup>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
      <div class="table-header">
          {{col.field}}
      </div>
    </th>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
  <tr>
    <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
      {{rowData[col.field]}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
```

Here, all the columns are dynamic and most of the time more than 100 different kind of column names.
For Ex: Columns names like

Also, we need to wrap the columns contains less text for ex: ID column
[image]

I need to achieve this with vertical&horizontal scroll. Can you help me on this?

Appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

This will create table columns with width `200px`.

```
<colgroup>
    <col *ngFor="let col of columns" style="width: 200px">
</colgroup>
```

This will create table columns with equally distributed width.

```
<colgroup>
    <col *ngFor="let col of columns">
</colgroup>
```

Complete code is available in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-frjavy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: I really appreciate your immediate response. Here, all the columns are dynamic and most of the time more than 100 different kind of column names. Also, we need to wrap the columns contains less text for ex: ID column. I forgot to add this my post. Now, I have update my post